# R: raster comes up with NAs even though values were added

Tags: r, modeling, r-raster

When I make a raster from scratch and use `length(is.na(raster))` I get all cells as NA, but if I enter the code `raster[]` I receive the cell values.

I have used `...vals=0`when making the raster to set up a raster with all 0
I have also tried `raster[]<-0` which makes all my values 0 but still shows 25 NAs.

```
library(raster)

size<-5
resol<-5
popseq<-seq(1,100,1)
stage1<-raster(nrow=size,ncol=size,xmn=0,xmx=(size*resol),ymn=0,ymx=(size*resol),resolution=resol,vals=0)
stage1[]<-sample(popseq,size*size, replace=T)
length(is.na(stage1))
#> [1] 25
stage1[1:(size*size)]
#> [1]  48  24  33   6 100  18  31  10  40  55  15  56  27  24  16  78  93  14  95  86  87  56  90  53  55
length(is.na(stage1))
#> [1] 25
```

This is not just an interesting problem, but I believe it also leads to my "non-conformable arguments"-Errors downstream (I am working on a post regarding that bit of code atm, it is a little more involved).

I *may* be missing something frustratingly obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a little involved, so please bear with me.

First of all, think about the following code:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

What result would you expect to get from the following line?

```
length(is.na(x))
```

If you think the answer should be zero, that's wrong. The answer is 5. Look:

```
is.na(x)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The line `is.na(x)` gives a logical vector of the same length as `x`. So the `length` of `is.na(x)` is 5. If you want the function that will give zero length it should be:

```
length(which(is.na(x)))
#> [1] 0
```

---

*However*, that's not the sole reason why your code doesn't work as expected. The reason is that `is.na` is a generic function. This means that package developers who create a new class of object (such as a `Raster` in the package you are using) can write their own version of `is.na` to handle objects of that class appropriately.

In the case of `Raster`, the authors of the package have indeed defined their own version of `is.na`. You can see it in the package's source code [here](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/blob/41ea0f15b49fcc4ea4e0a3df73768cea4c1d2d74/R/is.na.R#L1). Unusually, instead of returning a logical `TRUE` or `FALSE` it returns the original `Raster` with the same dimensions, but with all of its values set to zero. Look:

```
is.na(stage1)
#> class      : RasterLayer 
#> dimensions : 5, 5, 25  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#> resolution : 5, 5  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 25, 0, 25  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : layer 
#> values     : 0, 0  (min, max)
```

Now, it so happens that the authors of `Raster` have defined a generic `length` method too, which is defined [here](https://github.com/rspatial/raster/blob/58cf107b04a0b727a392534b3189cdf5c765990b/R/ncell.R#L23). That means that the object returned by `is.na(stage1)` will have length 25.

So if you want to demonstrate that there are no NA values in your raster, what you really want to do is replace

```
length(is.na(stage1))
```

with

```
length(which(is.na(stage1[1:(size*size)])))
#> [1] 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `length(is.na(stage1))` is not going to give you the number of NAs. It will give you the length of the returned vector (e.g. `length(is.na(c(NaN,5,6,NaN)))` equals 4). `sum(is.na(stage1))` would be more appropriate here, but you are actually not calling the values when you call the entire raster object. This would be the way to do what you want:

```
sum(is.na(getValues(stage1)))
# [1] 0
```